# Selenium (chromedriver) issue after chrome update to 118 version - can not find element by xpath id etc

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I can not find solution for my case. I have problem with my python scripy which is using chromedriver.
As I mentioned in title - can not find element on popup window.

code excerpt which is crashing:

```
window_handler_variable.maximize_window()  // PASS 
xpathFileDescription = '//*[@id="arid_WIN_0_8"]'
FileDescription = window_handler_variable.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpathFileDescription) // FAIL
```

**window_handler_variable.maximize_window()** -> this one is working so I assume that I am working on proper window and window handler veriable is fine.

***xpathFileDescription = '//*[@id="arid_WIN_0_8"]'*** -> this one also seems to be OK. No any changes on web page. BTW checked also by ID method.

Do you have any idea why I can not find proper element in that case ? just wanted to add that it was working fine on chrome 117 version and previous and it stopped working after update to 118. I can not downgrade the browser :(

checked id and xpath method. checked name of element on web page. nothing happend.
checked different combinations like FileDescription = window_handler_variable.find_element(by=By.XPATH, '//*[@id="arid_WIN_0_8"]')  etc
Just want to get this element and be able to click it.

Comment: Hello, Which selenium version are you using?

Comment: Hello, It was a good idea. I was using 4.11.2. Checked after update to 4.14.0 - same issue :(

Comment: Hi again, I did, its works. selenium version 3.14.0 Is your goal to download images?  
It's only downloading 50 images right now, I don't understand reason.

Comment: Thanks @Laura for yor help. Actually I  have fund the problem. noticed that I have some small popup window during the operation and after turning it off I had to update current_window_handle because it changed. So adding window_handler_variable = driver.current_window_handle  and than switching to that window resolved that problem. Simple as that but had no idea why maximize_window() was working on that window without updating the window handle.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    ...
    #window_handler_variable.maximize_window()  // PASS
    xyz = driver.current_window_handle
    driver.switch_to.window(xyz)
    xpathFileDescription = '//*[@id="arid_WIN_0_8"]'
    FileDescription = window_handler_variable.find_element(by=By.XPATH, 
    value=xpathFileDescription) // PASS

Comment: You're welcome, see you